# EF Core change tracking - issue with original values and altered values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, repository-pattern, ef-core-2.0

I have Net core API configured with .net core 2.0 and EF core 2.0. it contains repository pattern architecture.

Now, I am trying to implement Audit log for each save change using EF change tracker.

> **My Issue : Whenever I tries to add a log for edit/modification endpoint, the original value and current value remain same and it's newly updated value. so in that way I am not able to track the modification or a change.**

Here is my **ApplicationContext** file where I have overridden save call.

```
 public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options: options) { }

    public DbSet<Item> Item { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChangeLog> ChangeLog { get; set; }        

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries();

        foreach (var change in modifiedEntities)
        {
            var entityType = change.Entity.GetType().Name;
            if (entityType == "LogItem")
                continue;

            if (change.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                foreach (var prop in change.OriginalValues.Properties)
                {
                    var id = change.CurrentValues["Id"].ToString();

                    //here both originalValue and currentValue  are same and it's newly updated value 
                    var originalValue = change.OriginalValues[prop]?.ToString();
                    var currentValue = change.CurrentValues[prop]?.ToString();
                    if (originalValue != currentValue)
                    {
                        ChangeLog.Add(
                            new ChangeLog()
                            {
                                CreationDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                                CreationUserId = 1,
                                Log = $"Edited item named {prop.Name} in {entityType} Id {id}.",
                                OldValue = originalValue,
                                NewValue = currentValue,
                                TableName = entityType,
                                FieldName = prop.Name
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Here is my base repository.

```
public class EntityBaseRepository<T> : IEntityBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IFullAuditedEntity, new()
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext context;

    public EntityBaseRepository(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public virtual T GetSingle(int id) => context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    public virtual T Add(T entity) => Operations(entity: entity, state: EntityState.Added);

    public virtual T Update(T entity) => Operations(entity: entity, state: EntityState.Modified);

    public virtual T Delete(T entity) => Operations(entity: entity, state: EntityState.Deleted);

    public virtual T Operations(T entity, EntityState state)
    {
        EntityEntry dbEntityEntry = context.Entry<T>(entity);

        if (state == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entity.CreationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            entity.CreationUserId = 1;

            context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else if (state == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            entity.LastModificationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            entity.LastModificationUserId = 1;

            //var local = context.Set<T>().Local.FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.Id.Equals(entity.Id));
            //if (local != null)
            //{
            //    context.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;
            //}

            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else if (state == EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            entity.DeletionFlag = true;
            entity.DeletionUserId = 1;
            entity.DeletionDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        return entity;
    }

    public virtual void Commit() => context.SaveChanges();

}
```

And Lastly my controller with end point for put.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Item")]
public class ItemController : Controller
{
    private readonly IItemRepository repository;
    private readonly IChangeLogRepository changeLogRepository;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public ItemController(IItemRepository repository, IChangeLogRepository _changeLogRepository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.changeLogRepository = _changeLogRepository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult Put([FromBody]ItemDto transactionItemDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (transactionItemDto.Id <= 0)
        {
            return new NotFoundResult();
        }

        Item item = repository.GetSingle(transactionItemDto.Id); //find entity first

        if (item == null)
        {
            return new NotFoundResult();
        }

        //map all the properties and commit
        var entity = mapper.Map<Item>(transactionItemDto);
        var updatedItem = repository.Update(entity);
        repository.Commit();

        return new OkObjectResult(mapper.Map<Item, ItemDto>(source: updatedItem));
    }
}
```

I am not sure where I am doing any mistake, I tried to check this case in SO, but no luck.
any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the issue with your code. In your controller:

```
    //map all the properties and commit
    var entity = mapper.Map<Item>(transactionItemDto);
    var updatedItem = repository.Update(entity);
    repository.Commit();
```

In that code you are taking your DTO and mapping it to a new instance of Item. That new instance of Item knows *nothing* of the current database values, that is why you are seeing the same new values for both OriginalValue and CurrentValue.

If you reuse the Item item variable that you get in this line:

```
Item item = repository.GetSingle(transactionItemDto.Id); //find entity first
```

Note, you'll need to get the entity with tracking on however, vs how your repository GetSingle does it with AsNoTracking. If you use that item (which now has the original/current database values) and map your transactionItemDto properties onto it like this:

```
var entityToUpdate = mapper.Map<ItemDto, Item>(transactionItemDto);
```

Then, when you call your repository.Update method passing it entityToUpdate, I believe you'll see the correct before/after values.

.
.
.
.

Old (**wrong**) answer I originally posted:
In your ApplicationContext code you have the following loop

```
foreach (var prop in change.OriginalValues.Properties)
```

I believe that is what is causing your original value/current values to be the same because you are looping over the original values properties. Try changing that loop to:

```
foreach (var prop in change.Properties)
```

Then, try reading the values off each property via the prop variable like so:

```
var currentValue = prop.CurrentValue;
var originalValue = prop.OriginalValue;
```

EDIT: Ah - I see now that in your code you are trying to read the original value from the change.OriginalValues collection, so I don't think this is going to help.

Comment: I am still gettting new values only, I have updated my code and used properties directly from change

Comment: yeah, I was afraid of that, sorry - see my edit at the bottom of my answer - I didn't notice that at first

Comment: sure. no problem. thanks for helping. I will try something else.

Comment: @Bharat I made another update - I think I found the problem

Comment: you are right my friend, issue was with this GetSingle() method on base repo where I used this ASNoTracking(). Thank you for taking your time to investigate this issue. It really helped me.

Answer (score 4):

I am not using the repository pattern, but I have implemented a very similar audit log for EF Core 2.1.  I loop through the list of changes that are being tracked by the entity framework change tracker, and log them.

What I have noticed is that when I want to update an entity, there are two ways to do it.  One is that I read the existing entity from the database, reassign the variable, then save it.  The second way is to simply create an object, attach it to the database context, and set the property I want to update to the modified state.  When I do this, my auditing won't work for the original value, since the original value was never actually read from the database.

examples:

```
//auditing works fine
var myEntity = await db.MyEntity.FindAsync(entityId);
myEntity.Property = newValue;
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

```
//auditing can't track the old value
var myEntity = new MyEntity();
db.Attach(myEntity);
myEntity.Property = newValue;
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Here is the important bit of my auditing code for example

```
foreach (var entity in db.ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
    if(entity.State == EntityState.Detached || entity.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var audits = new List<Audit>();

    //the typeId is a string representing the primary keys of this entity.
    //this will not be available for ADDED entities with generated primary keys, so we need to update those later
    string typeId;

    if (entity.State == EntityState.Added && entity.Properties.Any(prop => prop.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey() && prop.IsTemporary))
    {
        typeId = null;
    }
    else
    {
        var primaryKey = entity.Metadata.FindPrimaryKey();
        typeId = string.Join(',', primaryKey.Properties.Select(prop => prop.PropertyInfo.GetValue(entity.Entity)));
    }

    //record an audit for each property of each entity that has been changed
    foreach (var prop in entity.Properties)
    {
        //don't audit anything about primary keys (those can't change, and are already in the typeId)
        if(prop.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey() && entity.Properties.Any(p => !p.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey()))
        {
            continue;
        }

        //ignore values that won't actually be written
        if(entity.State != EntityState.Deleted && entity.State != EntityState.Added && prop.Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior != PropertySaveBehavior.Save)
        {
            continue;
        }

        //ignore values that won't actually be written
        if (entity.State == EntityState.Added && prop.Metadata.BeforeSaveBehavior != PropertySaveBehavior.Save)
        {
            continue;
        }

        //ignore properties that didn't change
        if(entity.State == EntityState.Modified && !prop.IsModified)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var audit = new Audit
        {
            Action = (int)entity.State,
            TypeId = typeId,
            ColumnName = prop.Metadata.SqlServer().ColumnName,
            OldValue = (entity.State == EntityState.Added || entity.OriginalValues == null) ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prop.OriginalValue),
            NewValue = entity.State == EntityState.Deleted ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prop.CurrentValue)
        };
    }

    //Do something with audits
}
```

Comment: tried this, but not working. I mean the auditing still takes new value or both origional and current values

Comment: thanks for the example of your code of audit log, I can use that.

Comment: @Bharat did you see that part I mentioned about how to load data from the database when you set up the entity?  When you just call `context.Update(...)` it merely marks all the properties as "updated" without tracking what the old values were.

Comment: yes, I have checked that too and tried to load it as you suggested. but at last issue was on the repository method that I am using and it's a GetSingle(). anyway thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

there are two approaches for this:

```
var entry = _dbContext.Attach(entity); 
var updated = entry.CurrentValues.Clone(); 
entry.Reload(); 
entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(updated); 
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Or Simply do:

```
var persondb = db.Persons.Find(person.id);
db.Entry(persondb).CurrentValues.SetValues(person); 
db.SaveChanges();
```